# can we get the desired portion from the wiktionary api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediawiki, text-parsing, wiktionary

I'm using the wiktionary api to get information from the wiktionary.org..

I'm getting the data in the json format and i'm able to parse it too...

but i want to remove some portion of data from the result (in fact, i need only some data), but i dont how to remove certain content from the result..

the code i'm using is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="wikiInfo">&nbsp; contents</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=acting&format=json&prop=text&callback=?',
function(json) {
$('#wikiInfo').html(json.parse.text.*);
$("#wikiInfo").find("a:not(.references a)").attr("href", function(){ 
            return "http://sample.com/" + $(this).attr("href");});
$("#wikiInfo").find("a").attr("target", "_blank");  }
);
</script>
```

the above code renders the data as in the following page..

http://englishore.com/parse-wiki.php

But i need to scrap the Pronunciation and Translations portion from the result..

how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Please do not forget to include license information. I created a full working example at https://gist.github.com/674522, feel free to reuse the code. Beside the wrong selector, already mentioned by lonesomeday, the modification of href attributes did not catch all cases, so I fixed it.

Comment: I haven't worked out the example.. If it suits me then Which license information should i use?

Comment: Just include a message that says, the content is from Wikipedia and licensed under CC-BY-SA, and a link to the original article.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `json.parse.text.*` to access the relevant part of the object.  This is not valid JS syntax -- you can't use `*` in an array property.  You'll have to use array-style syntax instead:

```
$('#wikiInfo').html(json.parse.text['*']);
```